# Find ratio of the male in the data set and groupby occupation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

example data set below:

```
   user_id  age  gender  occupation        zip_code

0    1      24     M     technician         85711
1    2      53     F     other              94043
2    3      23     M     writer             32067
3    4      24     M     technician         43537
4    5      33     F     other              15213
```

so far:

i tried this however i dont know how to use np.where() to encode the data.

```
x['gender'].groupby(users['occupation']).value_counts()
```

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: ratio of male count to female in the data and group by occupation

Comment: Does this do what you want? `users.groupby(by=['occupation'])['gender'].value_counts(normalize=True) `

Comment: no, i am able to group the data by occupation and get M and F count for gender by this: x['gender'].groupby(users['occupation']).value_counts() , i need to find the ratio with the help of np.where()

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal can you share the expected output

Comment: From the Gender column i want to find the ratio of M and F and group by each occupation